# ODL DLUX blank screen

Tags: opendaylight, sdn

When I enter the site localhost:8181/index.html automatically redirects to localhost:8181/index.html#/topology without asking to log and showing a blank site. This is happening to me with Nitrogen and Carbon but, Beryllium works fine.

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Do you install feature `odl-dlux-all` in both versions?

Comment: Yeah I did. Actually in last versions the package is called odl-dlux-core but well, does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of OpenDaylight have split DLUX and DLUX Apps to make maintenance easier.

Install and start OpenDaylight Nitrogen:

```
sudo dnf install -y http://cbs.centos.org/repos/nfv7-opendaylight-7-release/x86_64/os/Packages/opendaylight-7.0.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
sudo systemctl start opendaylight
```

Connect to the Karaf shell:

```
ssh -p 8101 karaf@localhost
```

See the available DLUX features:

```
opendaylight-user@root>feature:list | grep dluxapps
odl-dluxapps-yangutils
odl-dluxapps-yangui
odl-dluxapps-topology
odl-dluxapps-yangvisualizer
odl-dluxapps-applications
odl-dluxapps-yangman
odl-dluxapps-nodes
features-dluxapps
```

Install the one you're interested in:

```
opendaylight-user@root>feature:install odl-dluxapps-topology
```

In a browser on the same machine:

```
http://localhost:8181/index.html#/yangui/index
```

Login with admin/admin and things should work.

[Here are the DLUX docs](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-carbon/getting-started-guide/common-features/dlux.html).

Overall, DLUX isn't really a focus of OpenDaylight development. Most developers never use it, and most vendors don't package it as a product. You can reliably get whatever info you need from OpenDaylight using the northbound REST interface ([example REST calls](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=netvirt.git;a=tree;f=resources/commons;hb=HEAD)).

Update: [OpenDaylight DLUX is Archived](https://jira.opendaylight.org/browse/TSC-93?), will not ship with versions of ODL Oxygen (8) and later. It's not a priority of the current developers. Contributions welcome if it's a priority to you.

Comment: Really appreciate the answer! :))